# How to stick a div to the footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a menu in `div.wrapper`, I want the `div.wrapper` to stick to the footer

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>1.</li>
            <li>2.</li>
            <li>3.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    <div id="footer-menu"></div>
</div>
```

How I can do that? My code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hnuye) . I cant move this menu from `.wrapper` to `.footer`. If I move scroll on page I want to have this menu stick with my footer.

Comment: `$('#menu').appendTo('.footer')` moves the menu to the footer, is that what you're looking for ?

Comment: `position:fixed` that's all

Comment: move `<div id="menu">` to footer

Comment: What do you mean by `make stick it in`? Are you trying to position it?

Comment: No no,I have to have this menu in wrapper I cant move it by jQuery

Comment: Without jQuery, you can only position it with CSS. (position: fixed; bottom: 0;) on your #menu.

Comment: @Niranjan Borawake: I need sticky footer (Im using Ryan Fait's css trick) and also I need to have stick this menu like it was in footer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjan_borawake/Hnuye/10/). I think this way you can achieve it. You don't need any JavaScript/ JQuery code to do it only CSS should be sufficient.

Changes in CSS classes :

```
.footer {
    position : fixed;
    bottom : 0;
    height: 155px;
    background-color : red;
    width : 100%;
}

#menu{
    position : fixed;
    bottom : 60px;
    z-index : 1;
}
```

`position:fixed` will take care of window scroll. Take a look at `bottom` property added to both the `classes`. For `footer` it is `0` where as for `menu` it is `60px`. You can change `bottom` value in `menu` to position it the way you want.`z-index` will bring it above the `footer`.

Also, you should use `footer` [tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer) rather than a div with class `footer`.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
$('#menu').appendTo('.footer').css('position','fixed');
```

If you just want to move use this:

```
$('#menu').appendTo('.footer');
```

And if you want when you scroll use something like this:

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
//code in when to move
var t = $(window).scrollTop();
if(t>300)
    $('#menu').appendTo('.footer');
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hnuye/4/)

[demo with scroll](http://jsfiddle.net/Hnuye/5/)